# Java ConcurrentModificationException problems with classes

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel

I am essentially doing the following:
Creating an object (for example a weapon object), that automatically adds that object to a list off all of those types of objects (`ArrayList<Weapons>`).

JPanel paints every 10 seconds with an updater thread that iterates through the `ArrayList<Weapons>`.  I am also sending 'questions' to a server on another machine, i.e. asking if that weapon is allowed.  If it is not, the weapon object is modified by the client computer.  However, whenever I modify it, I receive a ConcurrentModificationException.  Instead of crashing, which I actually hope it would do at this point, since the method that changes the weapon object is on a different thread, the whole program just locks up.

I have more than 1000 lines of code in this program, and more than three threads running that access the list, so if you need any code please ask but I'd rather not post right now because in my mind this seems like a trivial question for an expert at threads.

Thanks!

(Object is made >> added to list of objects >> JPanel's "Updater" thread is constantly painting all objects every 10 ticks...
Server says that object isn't allowed >> A thread on the client computer removes that object (or toggles a boolean that says it is not visible) >> ConcurrentModificationException).

Comment: You may find [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) useful.

Comment: ArrayList is not thread-safe. So only one thread should access it at a time (iterating on it counts as "accessing it"). Or you should use a thread-safe list, like CopyOnWriteArrayList. The objects inside the list should also be thread-safe if they're accessed concurrently.

Comment: Also, if the objects contained in the list are weapons, it should be a `List<Weapon>`, not a `List<Weapons>`: each object is **one** weapon.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the above information was just an example.  If I had written it, it would be Weapon

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [Javadoc of `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

You describe multiple threads accessing the list, and at least one of them modifying it. So, all accesses to the list must be done in mutually synchronized blocks.

e.g. to iterate the list:

```
synchronized (list) {
  for (Weapons weapons : list) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

e.g. to remove an item from the list:

```
synchronized (list) {
  list.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: I tried this.  It works as far as the iteration through the list, but there are still external threads modifying only one object within the list, which throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a synchronised version of collection or list, i.e. `java.util.Collections.synchronizedCollection(Collection<>)`, `java.util.Collections.synchronizedList(List<>)`. Also, if you iterate over the list and remove items, ensure that use an implementation that enable remove item from the iterator. A good candidate is `java.util.ArrayList`.

Other technique is use "monitors", you can declare an attribute like: `private static Object monitor = new Object();` then when the code tries to access to the list, protect the code inside a `synchronized(monitor)` block. Using this technique you ensure that no other thread will be able to modify your list until no protected code is running.

Please, excuse my English :).